# singleton class that survives Process termination

Tags: java, android, singleton

I've read several post regarding singleton class destruction or singleton pattern is bad in android like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/how-to-declare-global-variables-in-android/708317#708317) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891186/static-singleton-lifetime-in-android)

But I am not able to understand how to declare a singleton class properly or use sharedpreference for persistance can anyone provide any example on how to maintain global objects across application or how to achieve this in proper way any help is appreciated.

Comment: @ user13 please share your experience for newbees like me. .thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html should provide you enough examples

Comment: @  0xDEADC0DE it does not provide any documentation on scenario like destruction or handling singleton if you found such documentation post the link i will happy to see

Comment: True, but it does provide examples for using SharedPreference for persistent storage, which is also part of your question

Comment: @  0xDEADC0DE right now  i am already using sharedpreferences with gson i m confused about proper way to achive this

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/how-to-declare-global-variables-in-android/708317#708317) link you mentioned is quite good.As my personal experience the best way to maintain global objects in an application is to use a class that extends from Application class, then you can manage objects by setter and getter methods in that class.This technically works like a Singleton in android except most of house keeping is done by android so it's very wise to use this mechanism instead of singleton.
On the other hand `shared preferences` has entirely different job and used for mainly storing some user data and behavior

Comment: @ user2921831 i have many global objects across application which i have to access many times so how to achive this

Comment: from `Application` docs: `"""There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way."""`

Comment: @ Shaya take a look at http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Answer (score 0):

To save data between process termination you have to use serialization in any form.

The easiest way is to use sharedpreferences + gson.

Singleton would not help because all data with the process will be wiped, OS have a handler to save state in "low memory" situations but it still uses serialization (bundles).

You may use singleton with sharedpreferences, data clients (activities) have to notify about destruction, so singleton can dump data. At start singleton will load data again.

But be aware of possible inconstancy - what if an app will crash?

Things get trickier with multiple processes in one application.

Comment: @ Maxim right now i m using same technique does it causes any perfomance headche

Comment: Edited answer, you may use singleton+sharedpreferences+gson, but you will get design headache... there are always trade-offs...