# maintain session variables in server side for restful web services in java

Tags: java, spring, rest, session, model-view-controller

This is my first post on StackOverflow, so please forgive me if I wrote something wrong.

I found this post useful  [If REST applications are supposed to be stateless, how do you manage sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions). in my case I am having 3 clients ios, android and web these three are communicating to server side application(a standalone spring application). the login and logout are processing in server side, so I need to maintain a session. suppose when the client gives login request I need authenticate and provide an access token back. The access token must be generated and stored in, something like session. The access token must be present in each request. Is there any way to pass access token while making the request?.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: One way to do it is to  create a cache of it or a reference to the object in the memory and using it as a parameter in the API.. you can pass it along the header as well

Comment: For reference : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25237409/1562755